# Getting the destination address of a datagram in GO

Tags: go

In C it's possible to setsockopt IP_PKTINFO.
Is there any way to get the destination address of the underlying IP packet in GO?

```
_, addr, err := d.conn.ReadFromUDP(buf)
```

Comment: The code is different for different operating systems. I don't know enough about OS level packet handling to tell you much more than that. On Windows it calls out to C libraries. Unix uses the syscall library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented this in a DNS library in Go a couple of years ago.
You can see the discussion in the pull request [here](https://github.com/miekg/dns/issues/95).

There was another [PR](https://github.com/miekg/dns/pull/192) making this public a year ago, so I guess you can just import that module from your code.